# Checkmarx Scan Report shows severity as High

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, xss, checkmarx

Maybe someone could help me with this one?
Checkmarx returned me it as a high severity and i dont have idea why?

Client DOM Stored XSS\Path 6:
Severity High
Result State To Verify

"The application's function embeds untrusted data in the generated output with append, at line
15 of /js/source.js. This untrusted data is embedded
straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject
malicious code into the output."

Code Snippet
File Name /js/source.js

....
468. success: function(response) {

....
453. .append($(`<option>${week}</option>`))
}

**[Picture for issue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Q1M.png)**

or this one

Code Snippet
File Name /js/source.js

....
109. success: function (data) {

....
113. $("#webpage").html(data).css('opacity', '1.0').fadeIn();
}

**[Picture for issue 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn9re.png)**

Anyone have an idea how to solve it???

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your paste. If you want people answer your question, you should format it well and make it readable.

Comment: Yeah, youre right. I added pictures from checkmarx report.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this one.
And maybe it will help some of you.

The easiest way to prevent checkmarx from displaying these errors again is to assign the data from the response to a variable and sanitize it with a function like below
(its just an example):

---

```
function encodeHTML(data) {
    return data.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

---